# Blur background behind spinner Angular

Tags: angular

I am using a spinner in my Angular code while loading any data. I have created a separate component for it(necessary files given below). My spinner looks something like this :

[image]

Now, I need to accomplish blurring of the background behind the spinner while showing the loading icon over it. Any idea how to accomplish it?

**spinner.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "loading-spinner",
    templateUrl: "./spinner.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./spinner.component.css"]
})
export class SpinnerComponent{

}
```

**spinner.component.html:**

```
<div class="spinner">
    <div class="rect1"></div>
    <div class="rect2"></div>
    <div class="rect3"></div>
    <div class="rect4"></div>
    <div class="rect5"></div>
  </div>
```

**spinner.component.css:**

```
.spinner {   
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1500;
    overflow: show;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }

  .spinner > div {
    background-color: #333;
    height: 100%;
    width: 6px;
    display: inline-block;

    -webkit-animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
  }

  .spinner .rect2 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -1.1s;
    animation-delay: -1.1s;
  }

  .spinner .rect3 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -1.0s;
    animation-delay: -1.0s;
  }

  .spinner .rect4 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
    animation-delay: -0.9s;
  }

  .spinner .rect5 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;
    animation-delay: -0.8s;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
    0%, 40%, 100% { -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4) }  
    20% { -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0) }
  }

  @keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
    0%, 40%, 100% { 
      transform: scaleY(0.4);
      -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4);
    }  20% { 
      transform: scaleY(1.0);
      -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a overlay div and show it simultaneously along with the spinner.

Css would be:

```
.spinner_overlay {

    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.2;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

And add

> `<div class="spinner_overlay"></div>`

to your template.

This will work!

Comment: yes it worked but the page beneath it still responsive as the spinner loads. How do I make it unresponsive?

Comment: Make sure z-index of the overlay should be greater than the z-index of the container.